# Is this a correct way to import and register Vue components (with lazy loading)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

### Question:

Is this how it works? Do I understand it correctly?

---

#### Method 1

When we **don't use** any lazy loading we are **importing** a component and then **registering** it globally, like that:

```
import contactForm from '@/components/contactForm'

Vue.component('contactForm', contactForm)
```

---

#### Method 2

When we're **using Webpack** lazy loading we are **importing** a component and then still **registering** it globally, like that:

```
const contactForm = resolve => {
  require.ensure(['@/components/contactForm'], () => {
    resolve(require('@/components/contactForm'))
  })
}
 
Vue.component('contactForm', contactForm)
```

---

#### Method 3

When we're **using Vue** lazy loading we are **importing** a component but are **not** registering it, like that:

```
Vue.component(
  'contactForm',
  () => import('@/components/contactForm')
)
```

---

#### Method 4

If you want to lazy load components-routes you just import them like this:

```
const contactForm = () => import('@/components/contactForm')
```

---

Is that how it works?

And also, how do you add a "group" name in the method 3? (to group multiple components into 1 bundle)

Comment: Yep, you've nailed it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for the comment. I just wanted to make sure it's correct since I'm a newbie in web dev. Hopefully it will help someone else

Comment: I'm not an expert but I have heard that bundling multiple components in one bundle in a webapp is an anti pattern. The best way is to split your code to many small pieces and load them lazily only when needed.

source: https://www.vuemastery.com/conferences/vuejs-amsterdam-2019/modern-web-apps-performance-tricks-with-pwa-and-vuejs